# Using Firebase push notification token for authentication - good or bad?

Tags: android, ios, security, authentication, backend

My company that I'm interning at is currently using Firebase push notification tokens for authentication from the mobile app to the backend and I am not sure if this is a good practice. The way it works is as follows:

- FirebaseInstanceID service issues a unique token for every device as
  soon as device starts
- Mobile user sends login info to server; if server authenticates, the
  mobile app then uploads the Firebase token to the database and it is
  stored with the user such that the token matches with the user
- On any subsequent logins, user sends the Firebase token retrieved from                FirebaseInstanceID service to the server; the server attempts to match the token with a user

  - On clicking logout, mobile phone sends an empty token (i.e. empty string) to the server with their associated username

I have a feeling this is a very bad way to do authentication but I don't quite know why. According to my research the conventional way to do is that the server sends a temporary session ID to client, client stores it securely, and sends it to server for any subsequent requests. Can somebody explain what's going on with this Firebase business and why its good or bad?

Answer (score 0):

The problematic your company is facing, from what i understand, it to authenticate devices with a back-end API.
Actually when it comes to mobile applications, it is a tricky question. If users do not have to authenticate personnally, you still don't want to open your services to anyone. So you want to have an automated authentication system that runs in the background of your mobile app and that identifies devices or app instances.

To do that you need two things : 1 - identify a device (or an app instance) in a unique manner. 2 - make sure that the used string to identify the device/app instance comes from a real device/app instance.

Firebase instance ID is maybe right now the best free way to do that. The mobile app asks for google services to generate the unique token. The mobile app then sends the token to your back-end API for authentication.
And then the back-end API makes sure, during authentication, that the sent token comes from a real app instance by making a request to google services. Google services ensure that the token was generated on a real device (android/ios) and refer to an instance of your app (and not a tampered one).

This is a good way of delegating security issues that I exposed above to google services (who probably are better than you if you're not a security expert).

Of course there are other security measures that you should take to ensure your back-end API integrity. Such as HTTPS, for instance..

So I guess when it comes to mobile development, we should hope for a better solution than that, but since there are no better solutions, using firebase instance id is not bad practice.

Hope this helps